# Autocompletion in Django + pydev

Tags: python, django, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I am trying to make pydev autocomplete my variables from model data, but for now I have been unable to do it.

I have configured the PYTHONPATH in

```
Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Python
```

to include both the django folder and my project folder.

Then if I have a model like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  id = models.IntegerField()
```

and from another file of the same django project I import this file

```
from MyProject.MyApp.models import Team
```

Code completion works if I do for instance (I use CTRL+SPACE to show me the autocompletion optiosn)

```
team = Team.objects.[CTRL+SPACE]
```

But then it does not work if I want to 'autocomplete' the variables of t. For instance

```
team.[CTRL+SPACE]
```

does not give me any options.
Any idea on how to solve the problem?
Thanks

**UPDATE:** I have been digging more about the origin of the problem and it is not related with the path configuration or the autocompletion configurations, seems that it has to do with detecting the type of an object (the system is not capable of detecting that team is a Team object, and therefore it does not show the object properties).

Answer (score 2):

Have you added your site packages and your project folder to the PyDev Pythonpath?

Right click on your project folder and...

PyDev > Set as PyDev project

Right click again and...

Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH

Click on External Libraries.
Click on Add source folder.
Choose your project folder and also your site-packages folder. If you're using virtualenv, and of course, why wouldn't you be ;) you'll want to choose the appropriate virtualenv's site-packages. You do not have to choose the system site-packages folder.

Now let's check the autocomplete settings...
Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Completion

I have autocompletion set on all but the closing parenthesis, with an autocompletion delay of 0. I would also not recommend turning on auto imports.

Hope that gets you going!

Comment: Hi Brandon,thanks for the answer. I have the same configuration that you propose in the autocompletion setup (I do not have either auto imports). I didn't have the src root folder in the pythonpath (the folder where my django project is located), I have put it in there but still no luck on getting the autocompletion :(

Comment: Hmm. You might try clicking the "Force restore internal info" button from: (Right click project) > Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

Model.object autocompletion is broken, or at least it was in 2008:

http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg52874.html

Are you using the last version?

Comment: Yes, I am using the last version of eclipse, django and python.

Comment: Then I would asume it's still a known bug.